# Store the multiple result sets from stored procedures to different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have around 30 to 40 stored procedures which have multiple result sets as output. My actual requirement is to count the number of rows from each of the result sets from respective procedures in SQL Server.

I can alter the procedures and use `count()` for each of the result sets. However, practically it's a tedious job to alter 30 to 40 procedures. Rather doing the same I was trying to use `openquery` process and store the output of procedures into some temp table.

However, in that way I'm only able to store the first result set, not any other later result sets. Even I was trying to achieve the same using cursors but doesn't work. Can you please help me some way?

Here is the code:

```
  create table Orders
   (
      Slno int,
      OrderID Char(20),
      NumberOfItem int,
      CustomerID int
    )

   Create table Customer
                 (
                   CustomerID int,
           CustomerName Char(30),
                   Address nChar(50)
                  )

   Insert into Customer values (1,'Piyu','Bhubaneswar'),
                         (2,'Ranu','Bhubaneswar'),
                         (3,'Tiku','Cuttack'),
                         (4,'Lui','Bhadrak'),
                         (5,'Wasim','Bhadrak'),
                         (6,'Vivek','Dhekanal'),
                         (7,'Romeo','Puri')

    Insert into Orders Values (1,'O1',2,1),
                              (2,'O2',7,1),
              (3,'O3',20,4),
              (4,'O4',2,3),
              (5,'O5',3,3),
                  (6,'O6',1,7),
              (7,'O7',1,5),
                      (8,'O8',3,1),
              (9,'O9',2,6)

    Select * from Orders
    Select * from Customer                 

    Alter Procedure OrderDetails
    @Var_TotalItems Int

    As
    Begin

        Select C.CustomerName,C.[Address ],O.NumberOfItem,O.OrderID   From 
        Customer C
        Join
        Orders O
        On C.CustomerID=O.CustomerID

        Select C.CustomerName,Sum(O.NumberOfItem) 
        [TotalNumberOfItem],Count(O.OrderID) [TotalNumberOfOrders]   From 
        Customer C
        Join
        Orders O
        On C.CustomerID=O.CustomerID
        Group by C.CustomerName
        Having Sum(O.NumberOfItem) >= @Var_TotalItems
    End

      EXEC OrderDetails 4
```

Here the procedures returns multiple outputs. My objective is to count the number of rows in each of the outputs without altering the stored procedure.

Comment: sorry my answer was wrong.you should google  OPENROWSET('') to execute store proc.i am not sure about your requirement.Passing different para value to same proc can return different rowcount.Also all proc accept different parameter and their data type is different.Suppose you hv one more proc which accept date as parameter.how will you pass value and how will you know it.

Comment: I've already tried with openrowset(). It's only taking the first result set but not the later one. 

Can you suggest me is there any way I can use some loop or a cursor to accomplish my requirement.

Comment: you hv not explain the whole scenario.i hope you are covering your original requirement in correct manner.Right not I see only one solution.Suppose you are using c#,.net as front end then you can execute proc from front end and populate say dataset.then you can usedataset.Table[0].rows.count,dataset.Table[1].rows.count and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the system variable @@ROWCOUNT to get the number of rows affected by your query.

The value of @@ROWCOUNT is updated with the number of rows affected by your last statement ( select / insert / update / delete ). so after the execution of your stored procedure, you can check the value in @@ROWCOUNT to get the number of rows returned by the procedure. Like this

```
declare @c int
exec OrderDetails
select @c =@@Rowcount

select @c
```

Here the no of rows returned by the procedure OrderDetails will be stored in a user-defined variable @c and you can use the same for any other operations.

Please refer [this Link](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/mssql-row-count.htm) for more details on @@ROWCOUNT

Comment: @@Rowcount will return the number of ows affected by your last statement ( select / insert / update / delete ). However, I also need to track the previous rowcounts as well. My procedure is having multiple outputs in resultset. So I want to count number of rows from all the result sets without altering the Stored procedure.

Comment: try inserting them into a temporary table or table variable so you can fetch them later as needed in any order

Comment: I've already tried to insert the result set into Temp table. However, the temp table getting only the first result set not the later one.